# Using recursion to raise a base to an exponent to an exponent

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm currently trying to use recursion to raise a base to a power of 2 and then that to an exponent, so it looks like `x^2^y`.

Here is my code:

```
def real_multiply(x:int, y:int):
    if y == 0:
        return x
    else:
        return x * real_multiply(x,(2**y)-1)
```

The base case `y==0` is so that `2^0` gives back 1, and the output would ultimately be `x^1`, which would give back `x`. However, when I run this code, it goes to the recursive limit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps I'm approaching this the wrong way. In the past, I've written a recursive function for just one exponent, and so I assumed it would work here as well. `(2**y)-1` doesn't reach zero, how would the program reach the base case to stop running?

Comment: @Tyler it is in so far as, if this is homework, that means you have a professor and/or TAs who are being paid to help you.  you should turn to them when you're struggling with the course material.

Comment: @dbliss I'm sorry, but we've spent a good amount of time looking through my questions now, and I can't help but feel that you're only here to distract me from solving my problem. You've really done nothing except look at past solutions, which didn't exactly solve the problem (Look at a comment made by Malik, wondering why people are raising to the power of 2). Now if you'll excuse me, I'd like to get back to solving my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursion is a little off. Since 2<sup>y</sup> = 2 * 2<sup>y-1</sup>, you have x<sup>2<sup>y</sup></sup> = x<sup>2</sup> * x<sup>2<sup>y-1</sup></sup>. Therefore, your recursion should be

```
if y == 1:
    return x * x
else:
    # return x**2 * real_multiply(x, 2**(y-1))
    return x * 2 * real_multiply(x, real_multiply(2, y-1))
```

(Here, I'm avoid the use of `**` altogether. Nested recursion!)

Comment: Why is everyone using powers of two?

Comment: Because the assignment appears to be to calculate `x^2^y`, not `x^y`. `real_multiply` is not a great name for the function if that is the case.

Comment: Sure, you could write a typical exponentiation function, then use that to compute `exponentiate(x, exponentiate(2, y))`, but that's boring. :)

Comment: Sorry, I had another problem in mind when writing this function. You are right, I should have named it something more suitable.

Comment: @chepner: Your function actually gives back a recursion limit as well.

Comment: I would expect to with a value of 10 or larger for y. Now that I think about it, you'll need to reduce the value of `y` much more quickly for this to be a practical algorithm.

Comment: `x^2` * `x^2^(y-1)` = `x^(2 + 2^(y-1))`, not `x^2^y`.  You want to partition the problem as `(x^2)^(2^(y-1))`

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand what you are doing in your recursion but this is a typical exponentiation function:

```
def power(x, y):
    if y == 1:
        return x

    else:
        return x * power(x, y - 1)
```

Comment: wouldn't you also need another base case for 0? ```if y == 0 return 1```. It might be overkill, but I think it'd be useful. I am also solving this problem and have the same code as this, do you think this would work well for ALL cases of exponents?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is already here.

From @MalikBrahimi

```
def power(x, y):
    if y == 1:
        return x

    else:
        return x * power(x, y - 1)
```

From @JacobMcCarthy

```
In [5]: x = 2

In [6]: y = 4

In [7]: power(x, power(2, y))
Out[7]: 65536

In [8]: x ** 2 ** y
Out[8]: 65536
```

The OP may say, "No, I need one function that takes only `x` and `y` as parameters.  OK:

```
def super_power(x, y):
    return power(x, power(2, y))
```

Comment: Wow! How nice of you! Is it right to assume that your function super_power works off of Malik's power function?

Comment: Sorry, I only needed one function :)

Comment: what about a function within a function?  like if you moved the definition of `power` to be inside `super_power`?

Answer (score 1):

Using Malik Brahimi's answer you could write a power function then have your initial call be power(x, power(2, y)).

Comment: I'm aware that I can use x**(2**y), but the problem specified that I must write a recursion algorithm.

Comment: I don't have the rep to comment so I couldn't put the part I wanted to which was the main thing at the top. I will edit it to give you credit

Comment: @dbliss I never said MalikBrahim's function is not a recursive algorithm. I said Jacob's "solution" is not recursive. His "solution," if you saw it, was to compute x**2**y. That is definitely NOT recursion

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here and under other similar questions considered the situation when exponent is negative.

Here is a workable solution:

```
def power(base, exponent):
    if base == 0:
        if exponent == 0:
            return 1.0 # 0 ^ 0 is undefined. Using 1.
        else:
            return 0
        
    if exponent == 0:
        return 1

    dbl_power = base * power(base, abs(exponent) - 1)

    # if exponent is negative, take reciprocal
    if exponent < 0:
        dbl_power = 1 / dbl_power

    return dbl_power
```